# Ubuntu Touch suggestion: porting LINE messenger app

Tags: ubuntu-touch, instant-messaging, porting

I am a Happy BQ E5 Ubuntu Edition owner
I use it as my everyday phone, and it works very well.
The only problem is, as everybody knows, the lack of killer apps.
I use LINE on an Android tablet, and I noticed that LINE team officially support Chrome and FirefoxOS too.
So would someone be interested in porting the app to Ubuntu Touch?
Sadly I'm not a developer, I searched for a way to contact LINE support team and asking them about it, but could not find any email on their site.
How could I contact them? Or are there any devs that would have enough time to port the app?
Thank you in advance....

Answer (score 0):

The company behind line is Naver.
This is there website:
http://www.navercorp.com/en/company/contact.nhn